# How do I change software center email address?

Tags: software-center

I made an error in my email address when setting up software center on new system. I have created an alias. Can I either change the address in the software center (I have made no purchases) or change the email address to the correct one?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/342069/ubuntu-software-center-wont-accept-ubuntu-one-login

Answer (score 1):

You will need to visit https://login.ubuntu.com/ to manage your account, including your e-mail addresses.